# class Couple (design)

Tags: c#, class, class-design

i'm learning C#. 
ok, i have a problem: 
i have a class :

```
 class Couple{
     private double first{private set; public get;}
     private double second{private set; public get;}
 }
```

first question: am i right, that these properities have public getter and private setter? (it's sounds strange, i know, but need to know difference between private/public field and private/public property with public/private set/get )

and second question.

if i want a class :

```
   class AnyCouple{
        public Type AnyCouple {public set; public get;}
        private AnyCouple first{private set; public get;}
        private AnyCouple second{private set; public get;}
   }
```

how to make it?
dummy questions, i know, sorry

Comment: Although it's perfectly valid C# to put your `set`s first and your `get`s second, by doing so you will confuse everyone who reads your code.

Comment: By the way, C# naming conventions promote pascal case for public properties (unlike Java). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, yes, you are right. The properties `first` and `second` have a private setter and a public getter. However, as written, your code won't compile. If you specify an access modifier on a getter or setter it must be more restrictive than the access modifier for the property and you can't specify an access modifier on both properties. Additionally, note that in idiomatics C#, we write the getter first and setter second and we give properties PascalCase names like

```
public double First { get; private set; }
```

This will achieve a property named `First` with a `public` getter and a `private` setter and it is written idiomatically.

For your second question, you should use [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). You could do it all like this:

```
public class MyTuple<T1, T2> {
    private readonly T1 first;
    public T1 First { get { return this.first; } }
    private readonly T2 second;
    public T2 Second { get { return this.second; } }
    public MyTuple(T1 first, T2 second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
}
```

But, this is already built in to the .NET Framework. You can just use [`Tuple<T1, T2>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386940.aspx). Note that its `Item1` and `Item2` properties (analogous to your `first` and `second`) have a public getter; it is backed by a `private readonly` field.

Answer (score 3):

The class you want is [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx).

As for the general principle, you want [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Regarding properties, you can apply a different access modifier to one of the accessors, but not to both (the one to which you don't apply a modifier uses the modifier applied to the property itself). And the applied modifier must be more restrictive, not more relaxed:

```
private double first {private set; public get;} // wrong, 2 modifiers

private double first { set; public get;} // wrong, a relaxed modifier

public double first {get; private set;}  // correct
```

[A nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75e8y5dd.aspx) on MSDN about that.

Answer (score 0):

As for the first question, the `private double first` means that both the getter and setter will be private. Really you want `public double first` and then control the accessibility of the getter and setter as you have done. I believe that when the compiler sees this kind of property declaration, it creates code for the backing store (always a private field) and get/setters as you specifiy.

As mentioned by @GSerg, the Tuple class is what you want.